# Using Nesbot Carbon to return date to arrival object accounting for business opening hours

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I'm trying to use [Carbon/Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#doc-method-Carbon-addBusinessDays) and [Cmixin\BusinessTime](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time) to return expected arrival DateTime carbon object, based on current DateTime. But also accounting for business opening hours.

I have an integer value `$days`, which I am adding to the current DateTime.

```
<?php

/**
 * @param int $days // example defaulted to 1 day
 * @return object
 */
public static function expected_delivery_date($days = 1)
{

    // the current date time
    $time = Carbon::now(get_option('timezone_string'))->addBusinessDays($transit);

    // return delivery date object
    return $time;

}
```

In this same php class file `Shop()` I am setting business hours using [Cmixin\BusinessTime](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time)...

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cmixin\BusinessTime;

class Shop
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        BusinessTime::enable(Carbon::class,[
            'monday' => ['09:00-17:30'],
            'tuesday' => ['09:00-17:30'],
            'wednesday' => ['09:00-17:30'],
            'thursday' => ['09:00-17:30'],
            'friday' => ['09:00-17:30'],
            'saturday' => [],
            'sunday' => [],
            'exceptions' => [],
            'holidaysAreClosed' => true,
            'holidays' => []
        ]);

        Carbon::setHolidaysRegion('gb-national');

    }

}

new Shop();
```

The problem is, even tho I have defined my business hours using [Cmixin\BusinessTime](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time) in my `Shop()` php class.

When using Carbon chain function `->addBusinessDays($days)` ([see docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#doc-method-Carbon-addBusinessDays)), today (time now) is **Sunday**, which means it should add 2 days because the business is not open today.

Currently `expected_delivery_date()` is returning tomorrows date (**Monday**). The expected result should be returning **Tuesday** date, accounting for `BusinessTime` opening hours.

Any ideas on how to add days to Carbon DateTime object and accounting for closed business hours, would be awesome many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`addBusinessDays` does not take open hours into account.

But as you have a fixed day duration, you can use `->addOpenMinutes($days * (8 * 60 + 30))`

When wanting to add days, it will depends on your input and business rules as Carbon instances handle a date **and** a time. So is it the same in your business logic starting from Sunday 00:00 or Sunday 23:59, what time is expected for the returned date. Does any day with no open hours counts for 0 and all other day (no matter they have 1 minute open or the whole day) counts for 1?